# What's the difference between react-navigation-drawer versus @react-navigation/drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-drawer

I am new to React Native and its my first post in Stackoverflow so my apologies if I did anything wrong.

I m trying to follow the online tutorials to install package react-native-drawer. 
However, the official doc asked to install @react-native/drawer.
What's the difference between the two and when should I use what?

Answer (score 0):

okay I think I have figured it out. The two are just different versions of react navigation. /stack is v5 and -stack is v4.